# How to store the located controls in a separate class file (library) and use these controls in my TestMethods class

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am not clear on how i do it with the manual code and not using the recorded code.

I have to write the manual code to avoid class complexity as i have to implement design pattern in the framework. Below is the code to identify a button control in my application. I have created a class called 'AddNewEntityControls', i have created a 'ButtonClick' method to store the control properties. i have a 'codedUiTest' class, where i want to use this button for click action.

below is the class which has the method locating the button control.

Please tell me how i can achieve a click operation on this button in my 'codedUiTest' class.

```
public class AddNewEntityControls
   {
      public void ButtonClick()
       {

          WinWindow MainWin = new WinWindow();
          MainWin.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = ValuesGeneric.WinTitle;

          WinToolBar ToolStrip = new WinToolBar(MainWin);
          ToolStrip.SearchProperties[WinToolBar.PropertyNames.Name] = "toolStrip1";


          WinButton AddNewEntityBtn = new WinButton(ToolStrip);
          AddNewEntityBtn.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Add New Entity";

          Mouse.Click(AddNewEntityBtn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the WinButton in one class, and then enact the `Mouse.Click()` in another.  Example:

```
public static Controls
{
    public static WinButton AddNewEntityButton
    {
        get
        {
            WinWindow MainWin = new WinWindow();
            MainWin.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = ValuesGeneric.WinTitle;

            WinToolBar ToolStrip = new WinToolBar(MainWin);
            ToolStrip.SearchProperties[WinToolBar.PropertyNames.Name] = "toolStrip1";


            WinButton AddNewEntityBtn = new WinButton(ToolStrip);
            AddNewEntityBtn.SearchProperties[WinButton.PropertyNames.Name] = "Add New Entity";
            return AddNewEntityBtn;
        }
}

public CodedUiTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void myTest()
    {
        Mouse.Click(Controls.AddNewEntityButton);
    }
}
```